# Automatically Spreading Object Keys to Variables

Tags: javascript, function, object, variables, assign

I've got an object with a series of key/value pairs. I'd like to spread them all out like this:

```
const { 
    filterTarget, 
    filter, 
    source, 
    minDate,
    maxDate, 
    skip, 
    limit,
    tracking,
    trackingList,
    sortBy,
    sortOrder
} = req.body;
```

Is there a faster way for me to do this, so that I don't have to write ALL of the property names, but can rather just spread them out automatically? Like:

```
SOMETHING_THAT_ASSIGNS_KEYS_TO_CONSTANTS = req.body;
```

In the end, I'd need the same result but don't want to write out all the variables if that's not totally necessary.

Comment: you have to define these variables for you to use them in the scope! the destructuring is only to assign the variables with values

Comment: Why would you want that? Just copy them in another object? `let cpy = {...req.obj}`

Comment: You can do `const b  = req.body;`, then use `b.filterTarget` etc.

Comment: My answer seemed like just a copy of @Taki's answer in ES5 .Just ignore that :) Sorry for the disturbance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that without assigning the to the `window` object, something that you should avoid :

```js
const obj = {
  filterTarget: "filterTarget value",
  filter: "filter value",
  source: "source value"
};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => (window[k] = v));

console.log('filterTarget : ', filterTarget);
```

However, the reason this is not advisable is because it can backfire. First, if the object you receive ever changes the keys it has, you may get an error :

```js
function applyFilter(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => (window[k] = v));  

  //using the expected values
  console.log(
    "Applying filter:", filter, 
    "\nsource", source,
    "\nfilterTarget", filterTarget)
}

/* time passes and  project changes */

//using the function with different values
applyFilter({
  target: "filterTarget value", //filterTarget was renamed
  filter: "filter value",
  source: "source value"
});
```

Second, if your object uses anything that exists in `window`, the global value would be overwritten and this can lead to errors. Even worse, you might never notice the error because the functionality might be used by a different piece of code, or even a third-party library. At worst, this could look like this :

```js
function useObject(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => (window[k] = v));  
  
  var c;
  if (atob) {
    c = b + a;
  } else {
    c = a + b;
  }
  
  return c;
}

//using the function with different values
var result = useObject({
  a: "hello",
  b: "world",
  atob: false
});

console.log("result", result);

/* third party code */

var base64Encoded = "REVBREJFRUY=";

var decoded = atob(base64Encoded); //error because it was overwritten
```

The problem is that this could potentially overwrite anything - `Array` or `Date` for example, which would break a lot of your code. But it's even more insidious with something like `atob` which, while not "obscure" does not show up THAT much. However, it could easily be used by third-party code or a completely different part of the application and it would randomly fail.

With this in mind, it is a better idea to move the properties in an object with a shorter name :

```js
const verylongnameobject = {
  filterTarget: "filterTarget value",
  filter: "filter value",
  source: "source value"
};

const obj = {};

Object.entries(verylongnameobject).forEach(([k, v]) => (obj[k] = v));

// OR
// const {...obj} = verylongnameobject;

console.log('filterTarget : ', obj.filterTarget);
```

Comment: I know you put a warning that the `window` version should be avoided but let me just mention why it's a bad idea. Let's say you receive the object `{a: 1, b: 2}`. You then apply this technique and you can do `c = a + b` and this works, you get `x = 3`. However, you change the object's shape down the line and it's now `{x: 1, b: 2}`, which means that the `a` does not exist any more. Most sensible code analysis tools (or just reading the code) won't spot the issue so it can seem safe, yet the line `c = a + b` would now throw `ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Comment: The other issue is, say, getting an object `{atob: 1}` - it looks innocent but it will *overwrite* the global [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) function. And this could come back and bite you months later when you actually need to use it, yet "mysteriously" doesn't work. Anything else could also be overwritten like `Date` or `Array`, which can also influence how any code out there works. You could break third party libraries by absolute accident and *again* never know until it's too late.

Comment: @VLAZ i agree, it's a very nice elaboration, feel free to edit the answer to add more details and explanaitions

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to dynamically create constants at scope level, but one can do so at object level using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
'use strict'

function createConstants(source) {
  const result = {};

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(source)) {
    Object.defineProperty(result, key, {
      value: value,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      writable: false
    });
  }

  return result;
}

const a = createConstants({
  filterTarget: 42,
  filter: 43,
  source: 44,
});

console.log(a);

// Throws in 'strict' mode, because members of a are constants
a.source = 0;
```